# Program runs fine when debugging, but crashes when running ordinarily

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django forms to change a user's password when they forget it:

```
#views.py
def change_forgotten_password(request, key):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ChangePasswordForm()
        return render(request, 'freelancestudent/change_forgotten_password.html', {'form': form})
    else:  # post
        form = ChangePasswordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.get(forgot_password_key=key)
            user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
            user.save()
            return redirect('/')

#forms.py
class ChangePasswordForm(forms.Form):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def is_valid(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['password'] == self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']:
            return True
```

When I step through my code using PyCharm's debugger everything works exactly as I want it to; if the passwords match it updates the selected user's password. However, if I run it as (`python manage.py runserver`) it presents the error:

```
AttributeError at /change-forgotten-password/wemnj8vvk37yvikf/

'ChangePasswordForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
```

at the line in `forms.py` which reads:

```
if self.cleaned_data['password'] == self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']:
    ...
```

Comment: `self.cleaned_data` is filled by the validation check. However, you never  call `super(ChangePasswordForm, self).is_valid()`. You also might not want to override `is_valid()` but rather override `clean()` and raise a `ValidationError` as you currently don't get a displayable error message on validation failure.

Comment: Where do I call that?

Comment: in your overridden `is_valid()` before accessing `self.cleaned_data`. But see above for the preferred method.

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel? https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L300

Comment: @dhke Works a treat. Put it as an answer so I can mark it correct, if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form.cleaned_data` is filled by `form.is_valid()`. You forgot to call the super implementation in your form.

```
def is_valid(self):
    return (
       super(ChangePasswordForm, self).is_valid()
       and self.cleaned_data['password'] == self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
    )
```

In general, however, I'd discourage overriding `is_valid()` and instead override `form.clean()` or similiar. As indicated by Brandon, django already does this in its own `SetPasswordForm`:

```
def clean_new_password2(self):
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('confirm_password')
    if password1 and password2:
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
    password_validation.validate_password(password2, self.user)
    return password2
```

You might go DRY and simply re-use the existing [`ChangePasswordForm`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L300), which accepts fields `'old_password'`, `'new_password1'`, and `'new_password2'` so you might need to adapt your template.